# Control Flow. Logic behind callbacks, promises, async/await. Kinda what's the point?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I think I know the answer to this but not sure.  Wanting to confirm more than anything. The question applies (I think equally) to all three async approaches (callbacks, promises, async/await), but I'll ask it in the context of promises.

As I understand it, asynchronous programming is intended (at least) for event-driven applications to perform tasks in response to events, without the processes of doing those tasks blocking the ability to do any other tasks (presumably in response to other events) the application. eg. one event might trigger this series of tasks:

1. Query a database for some data
2. Wait for the response
3. Manipulate the data from the response (or handle errors as needed)
4. Write changes back to the database
5. done.

In more traditional programming (eg. C/C++) there'd be a main function that calls all that, and might get something back from it.  But generally, the process of that main function, sitting around waiting for that to come back, blocks other operations (unless you start manually manipulating threads, or other stuff, that this JS async programming is presumably supposed to spare us from, right?).

But in the above example, supposedly, the (conceptual) "main function" doesn't need anything back from it.  Step 5 isn't "return some result I need to act on", it's "done", end of story. If I understand correctly, the above is more likely called by a listener. That listener was set up by JS/node's equivalent of a "main function" -- the code that runs from the entry point of the app -- which has long since ended and the listeners are now running the show. Anything else this entire app needs to do will be triggered by some other independent event, caught by a listener. (Not that this is the only way but as I understand it this is pretty common).  So perhaps the user sees the results, and hits another button or whatever to initiate some other, separate, independent, task with it. The above task is long deceased.

Ok... if all that's correct then there's this: For each of those 5 steps, we need to call them in succession. Each step relies on something provided by the one before it. So that process basically needs to be synchronous.

In promise code I believe it looks something like this:

```
askDbForData() // step 1
.then(responseFromDB => { // step 2
    makeTheDesiredChangesToTheData(responseFromDB)  // step 3
})
.then(changedData => writeBackToDB(changedData))  // step 4
```

Looks to me like ultimately this is chaining functions one after the other to perform what is otherwise essentially a synchronous task.

But but but... Synchronous... = blocking?

I've just realized how this doesn't appear to be very clear to me in most of the documentation/articles I've read on this. This is what I need to clear up...

I think the point is: the part where `.next(...)` picks up the result and sends it off to the next piece in the chain -- that part is "blocking" (though it happens in the blink of an eye so it's kinda moot), but each of those (presumably time consuming) functions (like `askDbForData()`) -- which are supposed to be asynchronous, and return promises -- do their thing separately and independently of any other control flow, etc, thus not blocking anything.

In other words, the promise chain itself is synchronous, but each piece along the way is asynchronous.  The kicker, I think: Not asynchronous to other tasks in the same chain, but asynchronous to everything else the app is doing in other chains initiated by other events.

It might be that anyone reading this will read it and go "yeah well duh, that's the whole point".  Perhaps that's what I'm hoping. But if it is, it hasn't been clear in any of my research so far, so it's be great to get it clear from someone(s) who "get" it.  I think if all this IS correct, then it pretty much clears up nearly every other confusion I've had with this topic.

So... Yes this is long, but it is only one question. The question is:

Is that it -- is that the point -- or if not, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: synchronous != sequential, and asynchronous != concurrent, but I believe apart from terminology you did get the point, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks to me like ultimately this is chaining functions one after the other to perform what is otherwise essentially a synchronous task

No, the code you show there only performs the synchronous part of `askDbForData()`, then returns. If properly coded, this first part is usually nothing.

> I think the point is: the part where .next(...) picks up the result and sends it off to the next piece in the chain -- that part is "blocking" (though it happens in the blink of an eye so it's kinda moot)

Again no, the continuations are only called once the previous step is done. Once a continuation happens, the same split happens, first the synchronous (and hopefully minimal or non-existent) part runs then the rest of the function is registered as a continuation.

> In other words, the promise chain itself is synchronous, but each piece along the way is asynchronous.

Absolutely not, the chain of promises is asynchronous. `.next()` stores a function reference to be called at a later date, it neither calls nor waits for the call of that function code.

> The kicker, I think: Not asynchronous to other tasks in the same chain, but asynchronous to everything else the app is doing in other chains initiated by other events.

I've tried to avoid the word "chain" because it seems it's confusing you even more. It's not a chain, it's a tree, you can have promises executed in parallel or sequentially. So again, no.

Comment: It's not a tree, it's a DAG, and if you don't want to cause confusion don't speak of promises as something executable :-)

Answer (score -1):

Consider this.
You have a function A that returns a promise..a promise for something to come.
You also have a function B that does something else.

FunctionA().then(result=>{console.log(result)}).catch();
FunctionB();

If the promise in function A takes a long time to resolve..why not go ahead and do FunctionB while we wait?
Get it?

Comment: Ok, but what if function B needs the result from function A